# Yii2 Авторизация

Tags: yii2, авторизация

Вводимые пользователем логин и пароль отправляются для проверки на удаленный сервер через soap. Если приходит положительный ответ, мне необходимо авторизовать пользователя на сайте (Yii2 advanced).
Подскажите как это сделать? У меня нет локальной базы данных и нет полного списка пользователей, чтобы вписать его в массив в модели User как это сделано в Yii2 basic.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После положительного ответа необходимо авторизовать пользователя, значит вызвать метод [`yii\web\User::login()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#login()-detail), который в свою очередь принимает два параметра - обьект реализующий интерфейс [yii\web\IdentityInterface](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-identityinterface.html) и время авторизации пользователя (время жизни куки).

Про аутентификацию можете прочить [тут](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/security-authentication/). 
Пример реализации без базы данных можно посмотреть в [basic шаблоне](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/models/User.php).

В зависимости от реализации, ключевым будет реализация двух методов `getId()` и `findIdentity()`. Первый будет возвращать уникальный ключ пользователя с помощью которого метод  `yii\web\User::login()` формирует параметр сессии и куки. Второй используется для проверки авторизации с помощью сессии или куки.

В качестве примера реализации интерфейса:

```
class User extends \yii\base\Object implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    public $id;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        //можно реализовать запрос на удаленный сервер проверив авторизацию
        $isAuth = Soap::isAuth($id);
        if($isAuth){
            return new static(['id'=>$id]);
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

Это может быть полноценная модель пользователя, можно добавить публичных свойств, и по soap заполнять не только id но и другие данные.

Ну и пример для авторизации:

```
public function actionLogin($login, $password){
    $id = Soap::auth($login, $password);
    $user = new User(['id'=>$id]);
    Yii::$app->user->login($user, 100);
    ...
}
```

Надеюсь мысль примерно ясна. Примеры не являются истиной, все зависит от вашей реализации и подхода к решению.

Comment: А возможно сделать авторизацию таким образом: я проверяю данные на soap сервере,  если все ок, в ответ получаю не id а сразу набор данных для авторизуемого пользователя. Например почту, фио и т.д. И после этого авторизую пользователя с уже полученными данными.
 В Yii1 это было возможно сделать, а здесь не пойму как такого добиться. т.е. нужно как-то так:: 
$data=array();
$data = Soap::auth($login, $password); 
$user = new User($data);
Yii::$app->user->login($user, 100);
при этом в классе User не должно быть обращения к soap

Comment: Да, почему нет, только ид, например можно  вычислить некий хеш из полученных данных. В модель которая реализует интерфейс, добавить публичных свойств, и создавать обьект как вы указали. `$data=['username'=>'test', 'email'=>'email@email.com']; $data['id']= md5(...); $user=new User($data);`, `class User ... { public $id; public $username; public $email; ...}`

Comment: Да вот в этом-то и дело, что так не получается.  public static function findIdentity($id){...} должна возвращать, как я понимаю, return new static (['id'=>'...', ..])  со всеми свойствами. Т.е само значение этих свойств нужно получать откуда-то в этом методе. А он статический и ниоткуда,, кроме базы данных, прописывания руками или в моем случае через soap, я получить не могу. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Ну все что кроме id нужно ведь как то получить, так что да. Не помню точно все данные он хранит в сессии или нет, стоит поэкспериментировать, посмотреть. В качестве костыльного примера вообще можно массив с данными загнать в строку и представить это в качестве id ([пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0b863655dd1e128e558c8027ab26179f957dcab4)). Не знаю всех деталий, поэтому только вам решать какой путь выбрать.